# How do I specify @Orderby for a Set<String> in JPA

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x

How do I specify @OrderBy for a Set? I want to force Hibernate to use it's persistence set that's backed by Treeset, and my understanding is that I need to use @OrderBy to trigger that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get ordered data, but put it into an unordered set? That does not make sense. Better use another Java collection, like a List or maybe a SortedSet.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
@OrderBy() // orders by primary key
private List<MyObject> objectList=new ArrayList<>();
```